# Problem in saving Python tkinter Canvas drawing as an image file using PIL Image and ImageDraw functions

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

Problem statement

I have written a code in Python on which a user can draw on a tkinter GUI canvas. The program is capable of taking the app's screenshot but **saving the canvas content to a viewable image file (such as .jpg or .png) is not properly done yet.**

Screenshots

[What I draw on the tkinter app's canvas.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VezR0.png)
[What the code (given below) saved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klUJ4.png)
[What I expect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj1HR.png)

I have tried and will expect

A number of possible solutions from the internet (including [Stack Overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)) have been tried but somehow the process cannot be completed successfully. After drawing whatever on the canvas, the saved image will have nothing but a dot whether it is in *.jpg or *.png. I need the image of the full canvas with all the colorful drawings on it in that saved image file.

For any reference, here is my code

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

X = 0
Y = 0

app = Tk()


def set_xy(click):
    global X, Y
    X, Y = click.x, click.y


def draw_line(drag):
    global X, Y
    draw_panel.create_line((X, Y, drag.x, drag.y), fill="black", capstyle="round", smooth=True)
    draw.line([(X, Y), (drag.x, drag.y)], fill="black", joint="curve")
    X, Y = drag.x, drag.y


def save(event=None):
    # ATTENTION: This is not working properly
    image.save("image.png", "png")


# App's drawing panel
draw_panel = Canvas(app, background="white", cursor="dot")
draw_panel.place(x=0, relwidth=1.0, y=0, relheight=1.0)

# Invisible canvas for saving as an image later on
image = Image.new("RGB", (draw_panel.winfo_width(), draw_panel.winfo_height()), "white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

# Mouse and Key bindings
draw_panel.bind('<Button-1>', set_xy)
draw_panel.bind('<B1-Motion>', draw_line)
app.bind('<s>', save)  # press 's' to save the drawing as .png

app.mainloop()
```

Addition Informations:

---

- **HOST:** Windows 10 Version 20H2 (OS Build 19042.2130)
- **IDE:** PyCharm 2022.2 (Community Edition) (Build #PC-222.3345.131)
- **Language:** Python 3.10.6
- **Framework**: tkinter Tk/Tcl 8.6
- **Library:** pillow 9.2.0

> *Any solution shall be highly appreciated, and I shall be thankful.*

Comment: Post the code in the question, not in a link.

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

That's a nice idea and there is just one piece missing. You set the size of the image to the size of the canvas before you call `mainloop()` for the first time. The canvas does not have a size at this time because the window has not been initiated, yet.

You need to force an update before getting the width and height. Then, it works fine:

```
# Invisible canvas for saving as an image later on
draw_panel.update()
image = Image.new("RGB", (draw_panel.winfo_width(), draw_panel.winfo_height()), "white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
```

If you print the `draw_panel.winfo_width()` before and after calling the update, you see what I mean. Before `update()`, width and height are both 1. Afterwards, they are 200, as they should be.